# ¿Cómo captar el el cierre de la aplicación cuando se hace desde la barra de tareas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estimadxs, buenas, tengo una duda. Mi aplicativo hecho en C# presenta un error: El mismo es que cuando se cierra la aplicación desde la barra de tareas (dando click derecho):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O simplemente presionando la x:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta se sigue ejecutando en segundo plano:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se mata el proceso de manera correcta? Para ponerlos un poco en contexto, tengo una pantalla de Login, la cual una vez que está validado el usuario pasa a ocultarse con Hide() y cargo el Form siguiente. Utilizo hide para que el formulario mantenga datos. Si utilizo Dispose(), directamente no abre el segundo Form. ¿Cómo soluciono este inconveniente de mi aplicativo al momento de cerrarlo desde la barra de tareas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tienes dos formularios abiertos, uno de ellos ocultos, pues debes ir al **evento Close** del segundo formulario y ahí poner:

```
Application.Exit();
```

De esta forma cerrarás toda la aplicación.

Comment: Excelente, muchísimas gracias