# Cómo cerrar mi aplicación en Windows forma desde cualquier formulario sin acceder al primero?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

Estoy incursionando en la programación c# con windowsform y me surgió una problemática, necesito cerrar la aplicación XD...
Me explico, cuando paso del primer formulario este se esconde, y así con todos los demás, lo q necesito es q desde cualquier formulario yo pueda cerrar la app por completo ya que este último queda escondido (Hide()) y no se cierra. Intenté con el (Close()) y se me cierra la app completa y no me accede al form2
Mi código en el form1 dice lo siguiente:
(...)

```
Form2 a = new Form2();
a.show;
Hide();
```

(...)

Si en vez de poner Hide pongo Close, se me cierra el programa y no accede al resto del mismo, sin embargo poniendo Hide, cuando quiero cerrar el programa por completo desde cualquier otro formulario, se cierra solamente el formulario que estaba abierto y el form1 sigue abierto en 2do plano...

Comment: Como haces el pasar entre formularios? Sin ver el codigo que tienes es imposible darte una respuesta, debes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que tienes para que podamos saber donde estas cometiendo errores o que es lo que se puede modificar.

Comment: Hola!! podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]. No entiendo tu pregunta.. queres cerrar la aplicacion o no? porque en el titulo pusiste que si, pero en la descripcion pusiste que no...

Comment: entra aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/525962/c%c3%b3mo-captar-el-el-cierre-de-la-aplicaci%c3%b3n-cuando-se-hace-desde-la-barra-de-tare/525965#525965

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion para salir de la aplicacion, este metodo activara todos los eventos OnClosing, OnClose de los formularios y cerrara todo el programa

```
Application.Exit()
```